# Assets and reference

Tags: android, android-activity, reference, android-context

I want to know if is there a way to obtain a reference of an activity, from an other class, without passing it as parameter.
In particular, to open an Asset I need that the activity invoke `getAssets()`, but I haven't any reference to the activity.

Comment: I think you should explain your concept in more detail. I would consider changing it because it does not make sense to me to have sub classes which need access to the assets. But you could create a static resource class  where you add and remove the reference of the current active activity, depending on the acitivity lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate way is to pass the reference. You **can** store it as a static variable somewhere, but this is a very unrecommended method. If you don't have a reference, consider changing your design.

I'm not saying that only as an educative / theoretic argument only, but from (bad bad bad) experience.